# Woocommerce рейтинг в звездах

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

Подскажите пожайлуста - поставил плагин YITH WooCommerce Advanced Reviews

В карточке товара все нормально выводит в звездах рейтинг, но в каталоге пишет " 5.00  out of 5

Как в каталоге тоже вывести звезды?

Comment: При выводе на главной через

new WP_Query( array(
             'post_type' => 'product',
             'post_status' => 'publish',
             'posts_per_page' => 12,
             'tax_query' => array(
                  array(
                      'taxonomy' => 'product_visibility',
                      'field'    => 'name',
                      'terms'    => 'featured',
                  ),
              )));

Answer (score 0):

Нужно блоку присвоить класс woocommerce

Comment: Старайтесь отвечать более развернуто.